# Вывод всех ключей в списке из словарей

Tags: python

Есть такой список словарей:

```
[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]
```

Как из него вытащить все ключи `'name'`?

Comment: `names = [dict_['name'] for dict_ in list_]`

Comment: Как значение из словаря вытащить по ключу знаете? Как перебрать значения в списке знаете? Надо только совместить эти два действия.

Comment: @CrazyElf хех...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dicti = [{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]
names = [] # Массив в котором будут храниться имена
for i in dicti:
    print(i['name'])
    names.append(i['name']) # добавляем значение name в массив names
print(names) # ['Thriller', 'Crime', 'Drama']
```

И есть вариант более изящнее как написал выше asanisimov:

```
names = [dict_['name'] for dict_ in list_]
```

Хотелось бы посоветовать подучить работу с массивами, это ведь основы :)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, только начинаю изучать, но иногда случаются такие затупы во, вроде бы, не сложных вещах :)

Comment: Со всем случается, если мой ответ помог, то пожалуйста отметьте его как решение (галочкой). Рад был помочь :)